# How to append row(with mutiple input column and one dropdownlistcolumn) to table on ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I need to add drop down or list box in place of comment from model added at view. kindly suggest any other alternative method since i am new to this

Html code:

```
@model Sampleapplication.Models.samplemodel
<body>
            <table id="tabledetails" class="table table-bordered loaded-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                  
                        <th>  <p>Id</p></th>
                        <th>  <p>Name</p></th>
                        <th>  <p>Department</p></th>
                     
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
  </body>
```

on ajax success:

```
 success: function (data) {
                   
                         $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                             var rows = "<tr>"


                                 + "<td class='prtoducttd1'>" + item.Id + "</td>"
                                 + "<td class='prtoducttd2'>" + item.Name + "</td>"
                               
                                 + "<td class='prtoducttd11'>@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.sDepartmentList, Model.lstToDepartment, new { Name = "Departmentlst", id = "Departmentlst", @placeholder = "Select Deaprtment" })</td>"
                                 + "</tr>";
                             $('#tabledetails tbody').append(rows);
```

Comment: you can use div instead of table and you can use the dropdown. can you please share the sample data and dropdown that you want to show

Comment: I have edited my existing code, kindly check

Comment: Since i have more number of columns i need to display it in a table